# React Redux - this.props.actions.fetchPosts is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-async

i have issue with calling async action from my component, i think i did everything what was needed to work but seems like not, i used:

> mapDispatchToProps

and inside i return

> actions: bindActionCreators(fetchPosts, dispatch)

and i connect it.

After all these things, i try to call this action in my component -

> this.props.actions.fetchPosts()

in result i get this error in console -

> this.props.actions.fetchPosts is not a function

[image]

And i can not understand what's the problem with it as i did everything, here will be the full source:

Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import styles from './Home.css';
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions/counter';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';


    class Home extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
        }
        render() {
                return (
                        <div>
                            <div className="container">
                                <div className="banner_animated">
                                    <p> dadasda</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="container-fluid">
                                <div className="center">
                                    <input type="text"/>
                                    <button className="btn-2 btn-2a btn" onClick={this.props.actions.fetchPosts()}>Button</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                );
        }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return state
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(fetchPosts, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Action

```
import { FETCHING_WIN_RATES, FETCHED_WIN_RATES } from '../const';
import { firebaseDb } from './firebase';

const ref = firebaseDb.ref("win_rate");

    function fetchingWinRates() {
        return {
                type: FETCHING_WIN_RATES
        };
}

    function fetchedWinRates(winRates) {
        return {
                type: FETCHED_WIN_RATES,
                winRates
        };
}
// win rate champions
export function fetchPosts() {
        return dispatch => {
                dispatch(fetchingWinRates());
                ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
                        dispatch(fetchedWinRates(snapshot));
                        console.log(snapshot.val());
                }, function (errorObject) {
                        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
                });
        }
}
```

Write if you need some more files to help me, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you pass a function to `bindActionCreators`, it will return a function. See the documentation for `bindActionCreators` here (in the **Returns** section): http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html.

You are effectively assigning `this.props.action = fetchPosts` here, meaning you would call fetchPosts like so: `this.props.action()`.

If you want to access via `this.props.actions.fetchPosts`, you need to do the following:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators({ fetchPosts }, dispatch)
    };
}
```

Notice the shorthand `{ fetchPosts }` which is the same as `{ fetchPosts: fetchPosts }`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use bindActionCreators http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onClick: () => dispatch(fetchPosts(id))
  })
}
```

and then access via `this.props.onClick`